# Is there a means of setting way point poses or selecting a particular animation in "real-time"?

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

From the [animated_characters tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/intermediate/animated_characters), it seems that way points can be scripted, and animations can be selected/blended etc. Is there (or will there be) a means of controlling this actions via a plug-in?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3192/is-there-a-means-of-setting-way-point-poses-or-selecting-a-particular-animation-in-%22real-time%22?/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 319 on 2013-06-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2013-06-12**:
Admittedly, I ask before digging into the codebase (honestly a bit intimidated by some of the changes)

**Comment by [Andrew Hundt](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/685/andrew-hundt/) on 2014-03-18**:
I have the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can write a [model plugin](http://gazebosim.org/api/2.2.1/classgazebo_1_1ModelPlugin.html#a04ff4011ef896c0039d323be558d238d) to generate and control [animations](http://gazebosim.org/api/2.2.1/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Entity.html#a0ba2d580de851fabb0ef90f8e53bedcd)

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0